# Minimum vs. Minimal Elements of a Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose you have a set $\textit{S}$ with a generalized inequality $\preceq_k$. 
Is it possible for such a set to have a $\textit{unique}$ minimal element that 
is not a minimum element? I feel like it should be possible, but am struggling 
to come up with an example.